# Как присвоить результаты sql-запроса?

Tags: java, sql

Как я могу присвоить результаты sql-запроса в Java: каждый столбец в одну переменную, с каждой строки или, к примеру, на выходе только одна строка и три столбца. Как мне им присвоить String?

Comment: Используйте StringBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже писали нужно использовать ResultSet. Данный объект принимает всю выборку из базы данных по запросу. Пример кода вывода в консоль всей выборки по запросу:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Man");
while ( resultSet.next() )
     System.out.println(  resultSet.getInt("id")  +  " "  +  resultSet.getString("name") +  " "  +  resultSet.getString(3) );
```

В цикле while вызываешь метод next( ), который возвращает булеву величину и отвечает на вопрос есть ли еще  [кортежи](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/982712) в выборке.
У ResultSet'а есть методы *getXXX()*, которые возвращают указанный в методе объект. В качестве параметра указываешь либо название столбца из SQL запроса, либо его номер по счету.

Answer (score 0):

Получаете ResultSet от вашего запроса и получаете из него то, что вам надо.